# How to get a count of distinct values where one of them equals is requested

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with sales by customer and service. I need to get a summary of customers who had several services, but where at least one of the services satisfying given criteria.

So far I have

```
SELECT Account, Count(DISTINCT Service), bill
FROM jobs_by_service
GROUP GY bill
ORDER BY Count(DISTINCT Service) DESC, Account
```

When I introduce specific service I lose distinct service results. I suppose I need to use select within select, but seem to be going in circles.

Thanks

Comment: Can you set up an SQLFiddle with the tables?

Answer (score 0):

To get a summary of all services used customers who use a particular service:

```
SELECT Account, Count(DISTINCT Service), bill
FROM jobs_by_service
WHERE customer_id in (
    SELECT customer_id
    FROM jobs_by_service
    WHERE Service = ?)
Group By Account, bill
Order by Count(DISTINCT Service) DESC, Account
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be accomplished with a subquery.  You haven't given us table create statements, so I'm guessing a bit here.

```
Select account, Count(DISTINCT Service) as d_count 
FROM jobs_by_service Group By account
```

This will tell you the account and number of distinct services.  Turn it to a subquery that you can refer to

```
Select a.account , b.d_count
from jobs_by_service a
inner join   (Select account, Count(DISTINCT Service) as d_count
              FROM jobs_by_service Group By account) b
     on b.account = a.account
where criteria1 = 'hi' or criteria2 = 'bye' or criteria1 = 'ok'
```